# Show spinner next to navigation link when clicked

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a few links in my navigation:

```
...
{{#linkTo 'projects.trending' tagName="li"}}
    <a href="#" {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}> Trending projects</a>
{{/linkTo}}
{{#linkTo 'projects.all' tagName="li"}}
    <a href="#" {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}> All projects</a>
{{/linkTo}}
...
```

When I click one of these links, it will fetch data via Ajax and go to that route. But sometimes it takes a while to fetch the data, so I'd like to show a spinner. I currently already have a global spinner at the top of the page. It would be cool to show a spinner next to the navigation link that was clicked, so the user sees what page is currently loading.

What would be the best/easiest approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a span next to each navigation link that's hidden by default, and contains the spinner. Then onClick, show the span. Hide all of them after ajax is done.

Comment: The linkTo helper doesn't have events, as far as I know.

Comment: 'a' has events, so does 'li'